# how to point to a folder in shared hosted server control panel

Tags: shared-hosting

I wanted to deploy my project in shared hosting server.While deploying i found the below issues
1.I am not able to find how to point to my project folder.
2.how to set default document or startup page for the site.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Most shared hosting companies, when talking about PHP, will have a folder named `public_html` or `root` that is the primary container of your website.

Depending on the host and the language, this could change and you should check your service provider's documentation.

EDIT: Ohhh... Just saw the date on the post.